# Upload data stored in external SQL database

Tags: content-database, sql

I want to upload some data which is stored in external SQL database to SharePoint database and it should reflect in forms under SharePoint.

Comment: External database is MSSQL or others?

Answer (score 2):

If your database is SQL, then there is a built in feature to achieve this. Follow the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianragusa/archive/2014/07/19/configuring-sharepoint-2013-ect-amp-bcs-for-sql-connectivity.aspx)

For other databases you have to write a custom wcf web service. see [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/connecting-to-a-web-service-using-business-connectivity-serv/)